# iOS: How to copy contents from a scrollview into another scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

- Am created `UIScrollView` programatically and added multiple `buttons` into that.
- Its working well without any prob.
- But i need to create another `scrollview` by copying contents from previous scrollview.

**Query:**
 How to copy `First_Scrollview` content into `Second_Scrollview`

**Code:**

```
- (void)ScrollviewItems
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 5;
    for(int i=0; i<totalButtonsCount; i++)
    {
        CategoryItem = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, buttonWidth, 50)];
        CategoryItem.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        CategoryItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [CategoryItem setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CategoryItem.tag = i;
        [CategoryItem addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(CategoryItemAction:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [First_Scrollview addSubview:CategoryItem];
        x = x + (buttonWidth + 5);
    }
    First_Scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x,50);

    Second_Scrollview = [self.Category_Scrollview copy]; // Error
}
```

**Error:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIScrollView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: `[UIScrollView copy]` doesn't work like this. Easiest way to achieve your goal is to loop the subviews of the scrollview and add those subviews to your target scrollview.

Comment: UIView can be just inside one super view / parent. To copy it you'll need to recreate it and add as subview into second parent, iteration is your friend like Raptor suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by this for loop also

```
for(UIView *v in self.scrollview1.subviews){
        [self.scrollview2 addSubview:v];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy views in the way you are trying.

You need to do it as :

```
NSData * viewData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myView];
NSView * viewCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:viewData];
```